# How would I encode a forward slash (/) in a file name and not in an URL?

Tags: html, escaping

**How would I encode a forward slash (/) in a file name and not in an URL?**

I can't find anything on the web regarding file names, just URLs.

In addition, I do not want to use 0_5_oz or other replacements for the 1/2 oz.

```
For example: http://lemon_1/2_oz.php

http://lemon_1%2f2_oz.php resolves as http://lemon_1%2f2_oz.php  (creates and error)

http://lemon_1&#8725;2_oz.php resolves as http://lemon_1/2_oz.php (also fails)

I tried the following character replacements and both failed:

ASCII UTF-8: %2f

Unicode Character HTML Entity (decimal): &#8725;

Other options, but I also think they will fail"

&sol;

&#x0002F;

&#47;

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a forward slash in a file name where you are retrieving the file via the query string. The browser will pick this up and expect to find a webpage. Likewise, if you used this for file paths you would also come across issues.

Other unusable characters include (windows):

`\ / : * " < > |`

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that. I need to encode the / in a file name.

Comment: The answer is no, not possible.